# Why does this recursive peak filter written in Java not filter the chosen frequency

Tags: java, audio, filtering

So, I don't know whether I've implemented this incorrectly, or whether it's a feature of this kind of filter; but, I'd been trying to apply a peak filter to an audio signal and it wasn't working.
Some testing revealed that it wasn't filtering for the frequency I selected; but a nearby value, some of which are powers of 2, so, eg, filtering 4KHz actually filtered 4096Hz.
Here's the filter (it's from http://dspguide.com/ch19/3.htm):
SAMPLE_RATE is 88*1024

```
        class Coefficients {
        double a0=0;    
        double a1=0;    
        double a2=0;    
        double twoCos2piFreq=0;    
        double b1=0;            
        double b2=0;            
        double K=0;             
        double R=0;             
        double rSquared=0;

        public Coefficients(double freq, double bandwidth)
        {
            twoCos2piFreq=2*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*freq);
            R=1-(3*bandwidth);
            rSquared=R*R;
            K=(1-(R*twoCos2piFreq)+rSquared)/(2-twoCos2piFreq);
            b1=R*twoCos2piFreq;
            b2=-rSquared;
        }
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------
        // Source x, result y
        // y[i]=a0*x[i] + a1*x[i-1] + a2*x[i-2] + b1*y[i-1] + b2*y[i-2]
        private void recursiveFilter(float[] x, float[] y)
        {
        double x_2 = 0.0f;                    // delayed x, y samples
        double x_1 = 0.0f;
        double y_2 = 0.0f;
        double y_1 = 0.0f;

            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i){
                double xi=x[i];
                double yi=a0*xi + a1*x_1 + a2*x_2 + b1*y_1 + b2*y_2;
                x_2 = x_1;                              // shift delayed x, y samples
                y_2 = y_1;
                x_1 = xi;
                y_1 = yi;
                y[i] = (float)yi;
            }
        }
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        public float[] filtered(float[] signal)
        {
            float[] result=new float[signal.length];
            recursiveFilter(signal,result);
            return result;
        }
    }
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    class BandPassCoefficients extends Coefficients 
    {
        public BandPassCoefficients(double freq, double bandwidth)
        {
            super(freq/(double)SAMPLE_RATE,bandwidth/(double)SAMPLE_RATE);
            a0=1-K;
            a1=(K-R)*twoCos2piFreq;
            a2=rSquared-K;
        }
    }
```

and to test it, I fill a buffer with a sine wave of a range of frequencies, one at a time, apply the filter and measure the highest amplitude in the result.
Fairly obvious code, but here it is:

```
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    private void genTestSignal(float freq)
    {
        float[]  leftSignal=createSinWaveBuffer(freq,ONE_SECOND);
        float[] rightSignal=createSinWaveBuffer(freq,ONE_SECOND);
        denormalise( leftSignal ,inputSignal, LEFT_CHANNEL);
        denormalise(rightSignal,inputSignal,RIGHT_CHANNEL);
    }
```

The denormalise and normalise functions just convert to and from interleaved signed 16-bit values to single channel floats.
This samples the start of the signal, to find the largest absolute magnitude:

```
        private void findOptimalFreq(float[] signal, float freq)
    {
        float maxAmplitude=0;
        int peak=0;
        for(int i=(int)freq/2; i<(int)freq*3/2; i+=2){
            BandPassCoefficients signalFilter=new BandPassCoefficients(i,10);
            float[] normalised=signalFilter.filtered(signal);
            float loudest=0;
            // only scan the first part, since it's all the same
            for(int j=1; j<10000; ++j){
                float s=Math.abs(normalised[j]);
                if(s>loudest) loudest=s;
            }
            if(loudest>maxAmplitude){
                maxAmplitude=loudest;
                peak=i;
            }
        }
        log("freq,"+freq+","+peak);
    }
```

And, for completion, the code which steps through the audio range, testing each frequency.

```
                for(workingFreq=100; workingFreq<20000; workingFreq+=100){
                genTestSignal(workingFreq);
                inputShorts=new short[inputSignal.length/2];
                ByteBuffer.wrap(inputSignal).order(bigEndian ? ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN : ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(inputShorts);
                findOptimalFreq(normalised(inputShorts,RIGHT_CHANNEL),workingFreq);
            }
```

The output is logged to System.out, and copied to a spreadsheet, since it's CSV format.
Here's some of it, the left is the target frequency, the right is the actual frequency which the peak is at:

```
6200,6436
6300,6436
6400,6436
6500,6932
6600,6932
6700,6932
6800,6932
6900,6932
7000,7510
7100,7510
7200,7510
7300,7510
7400,7510
7500,7510
7600,8192
7700,8192
7800,8192
7900,8192
8000,8192
8100,8192
8200,9012
8300,9012
```

Any thoughts?
I've gone through the filter code over and over, and I'm fairly sure it's right; but there's no mention anywhere I've seen of this kind of "feature", so I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't solve the problem; but was able to replace it with a BiQuadratic filter from this site: [BiQuadDesigner](https://arachnoid.com/BiQuadDesigner/index.html)

There is a link to [java source](https://arachnoid.com/BiQuadDesigner/source_files/BiQuadraticFilter.java):

HTH anyone else struggling with this.